# Negative Consequences of deleting own Answers?

Tags: discussion

It happens from time to time that I find an answer of mine is less researched than another which was posted after, and adds nothing over the other. In these cases, I often delete my own and upvote the other.

Is there some algorithm that SO runs that could bite me for that?

Comment: If your answers are neutrally or negatively scored, then yes -- there's a similar system for answers as questions where you may be blocked from posting further.

Comment: @TZHX so is it better then to leave a decidely 0 point answer that has less value then the accepted one up? What about a positively scored one?

Comment: If you routinely delete your positively-scored content I believe it raises a flag for mods so they can see if you're rage-quitting or whatever, I don't think there's any other negative side-effects for it.

Comment: If the answer is positively scored and not fully contained in another answer I would always leave it as an alternative/completion to all the other answers. I would not like that SO loses content but of course it is your choice.

Answer (score 3):

*Negative* consequences?  No!  By upvoting the other answer, you help guide future users to the knowledge they seek.  By deleting your own answer, you reduce clutter.  This is what Stack Overflow is all about!

Now, if your answer is correct but approaches the problem from a different perspective, you might want to leave it, even if the asker accepted a different one; future visitors may find your answer more helpful.

But you aren't *required* to leave your answer up, and won't be punished for deleting it, even if it has a positive score.  The goal is to add value.  Heck, they award badges for this kind of thing!  I've got [Peer Pressure](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure), [Disciplined](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/37/disciplined), and [Sportsmanship](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/805/sportsmanship).

:D

Comment: Though if you will systematically start removing bad answers within a short period time, you'll probably end up getting your account banned for a certain period of time.

Comment: It's not really correct to say definitively that you *won't* be punished for deleting answers. You can be. Positive, negative, neutral: if you remove too many, things *can* go sour, either by suspension (if you appear to be ragequitting by deleting positively-scored answers) or automatic lasting answer-ban (if the answers scored badly). *However*, a few answers deleted out of a fair number of good ones won't hit any likely triggers, so there will be no discernible consequences.

Answer (score -1):

It depends.

If you only delete a small part of your answers, all will be fine - for you and also for the site if you only remove answers that add little or no value.

But if you delete many downvoted answers without having enough left alive, it would still be good for SO site (clean is beautiful) but **you** could get an answer ban for that. It is sad if you do that to make site cleaner, but robots are often narrow minded...

Comment: If most all of your answers are downvoted you're likely to get an answer ban *whether you delete them or not*.